# keyboard simulation not working in vitual machine

Tags: c++, virtual-machine

I have a C/C++ program to simulate key board strokes by using Windows "SetPortVal(...)" function, it is working fine in my physical laptop. However when I ran it in a virtual windows box, the simulation failed, that is the focus field did not get any characters input. The program ran well without any error, but just did not get any characters. Any one has any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the Winio library actually work with a Windows virtual machine since there is no physical hardware for `SetPortVal()` to access? Also what version of Windows are you using for the virtual machine? The internals.com page for WinIO says 32 bit windows applications.

Comment: Also please update your question with details about the actual virtualization technology you are using.

Comment: The virtual machine is 64 bits Windows Server 2012 on top of VMWare ESXi 6.0.0. I did not use internals WinIO dll, instead I used WInIo64.sys & my own SetPotVal code. It worked fine in my laptop.Thanks Richard.

Comment: If it is your own version of `SetPortVal()` then are you able to use a debugger to see whether you are actually talking to the correct interfaces between the virtual machine and the actual hardware and receiving the keyboard input? If you test with another application in your virtual machine does that application receive keyboard input?

Comment: @Richard I do not have any other software using this simulation. I do not quite get this: "the correct interfaces between the virtual machine and the actual hardware". The KB interface port numbers used are: X60 & X64 for key up/down respectively. What is the interfaces between the virtual machine and the hardware?

Comment: You want to simulate keyboard input but it is not working. My first question is whether an actual keyboard is able to communicate with an application in the virtual machine. So a standard Windows application such as Notepad should suffice to test that.

Comment: Yes. I can input key board characters into notepad after remotely logging into the virtual box.

Comment: Can you write a simple application that uses `GetPortVal()` to read the keyboard input and `SetPortVal()` to pass it on? In other words to write an application that uses your library in order to test that the keyboard ports you are using are correct for the virtual machine? Also can you use a debugger in the virtual environment to see what is happening in the application and the library with your `SetPortVal()`?

Comment: bool s = SetPortVal( 0X60, x, 1 );
DWORD x=0;
bool g=GetPortVal(0x60, &x,1);

Comment: bool s = SetPortVal( 0X60, x, 1 );
DWORD x=0;
bool g=GetPortVal(0x60, &x,1); Look at the 3 lines of code, the execution was correct, that is the x was what was written into the port, regardless debugging in physical machine or virtual machine. However I did notice that the debug value (the value of x after character '3' value mapping in my debug case), '3' appeared in the focus (right before bool s...)  in physical machine, but nothing in virtual machine. The virtual machine did not send my value to the focus. Help please.